# regulador numérico para enteros negativos en bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell

tengo un regulador numérico pero solo funciona para números positivos, y quiero que funcione también para los negativos, apenas estoy aprendiendo bash, seria de gran ayuda

`^[+]?[0-9]+([0-9]+)?$`

Comment: Para soportar negativos, incluye el `-` en el primer grupo, `^[+\-]?...`

Comment: gracias, fue muy útil

Answer (score 2):

No hace falta repetir el bloque de números, con esto hay suficiente:

```
^[+-]?[0-9]+$
```

Es decir:

- `^ ... $` para indicar que la cadena solamente contenga lo descrito en "...".
- `[+-]?` que haya un + o un -, opcionalmente (nótese que el `-` no hace falta escaparlo porque está al final de la expresión).
- `[0-9]+` uno o más dígitos del 0 al 9.

Ejemplos:

```
$ [[ 2 =~ ^[+-]?[0-9]+$ ]] && echo "yes"
yes
$ [[ -32 =~ ^[+-]?[0-9]+$ ]] && echo "yes"
yes
$ [[ .2 =~ ^[+-]?[0-9]+$ ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
no
$ [[ 2,3 =~ ^[+-]?[0-9]+$ ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
no
```

Answer (score 1):

Escríbelo así...

```
    ^[+\-]?[0-9]+([0-9]+)?$
```